# Drag <li> between two <ul> JS (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, drag

I am trying to build two ul in JS and HTML and drag li between them. (task to it without using jQuery)  I pretty sure that I do something wrong in

```
function handleDrop(e)  OR I need to rewrite all.
```

Hope for your help

this is a code that I have.

HTML

```
<body>
<ul id="columns">
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>A</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>B</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>C</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>D</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>E</header></li>
</ul>

<ul id="columns_1">
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>Ad</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>Bd</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>Cd</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>Dd</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>Ed</header></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

AND JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var dragSrcEl = null;

function handleDragStart(e) {
  // Target (this) element is the source node.
  dragSrcEl = this;

  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.outerHTML);

  this.classList.add('dragElem');
}
function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
  }
  this.classList.add('over');

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.

  return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
     console.log('handleDragEnter');
        e.preventDefault();

  // this / e.target is the current hover target.
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('over');  // this / e.target is previous target element.
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  // this/e.target is current target element.

  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
  }

  // Don't do anything if dropping the same column we're dragging.
  if (dragSrcEl != this) {
    // Set the source column's HTML to the HTML of the column we dropped on.
    //alert(this.outerHTML);
    //dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    //this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    this.parentNode.removeChild(dragSrcEl);
    var dropHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',dropHTML);
    var dropElem = this.previousSibling;
    addDnDHandlers(dropElem);

  }
  this.classList.remove('over');
  return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  // this/e.target is the source node.
  this.classList.remove('over');

  /*[].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
    col.classList.remove('over');
  });*/
}

function addDnDHandlers(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false)
  elem.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
  elem.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);

}

var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');
[].forEach.call(cols, addDnDHandlers);
cols


var cols_1 = document.querySelectorAll('#columns_1 .column');
[].forEach.call(cols, addDnDHandlers);

</script>
```

Comment: Drag and drop is pretty complex stuff, especially when it comes to connected lists, I would highly recommend a plugin such as [Dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula). Otherwise you may also need to polyfill.

Comment: I have checked this plugin. But.. I need to do it without any plugins. Thanks man. May be you Know links which can help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the dragged element from its parent. And not from the elemet that triggered the drop event. Below is the code. Have a look and let me know if this is what you wanted.

```js
var dragSrcEl = null;

function handleDragStart(e) {
  // Target (this) element is the source node.
  dragSrcEl = this;

  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.outerHTML);

  this.classList.add('dragElem');
}
function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
  }
  this.classList.add('over');

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.

  return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
     //console.log('handleDragEnter');
        e.preventDefault();

  // this / e.target is the current hover target.
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('over');  // this / e.target is previous target element.
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  // this/e.target is current target element.
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
  }

  // Don't do anything if dropping the same column we're dragging.
  if (dragSrcEl != this) {
    // Set the source column's HTML to the HTML of the column we dropped on.
    //alert(this.outerHTML);
    //dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    //this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    dragSrcEl.parentNode.removeChild(dragSrcEl);
    var dropHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',dropHTML);
    var dropElem = this.previousSibling;
    addDnDHandlers(dropElem);

  }
  this.classList.remove('over');
  return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  // this/e.target is the source node.
  this.classList.remove('over');

  /*[].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
    col.classList.remove('over');
  });*/
}

function addDnDHandlers(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false)
  elem.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
  elem.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);

}

var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');
[].forEach.call(cols, addDnDHandlers);


var cols_1 = document.querySelectorAll('#columns_1 .column');
[].forEach.call(cols_1, addDnDHandlers);
```

```html
<body>
<ul id="columns">
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>A</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>B</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>C</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>D</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>E</header></li>
</ul>

<ul id="columns_1">
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>Ad</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>Bd</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>Cd</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>Dd</header></li>
  <li class="column" draggable="true"><header>Ed</header></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Hope this helps :)